# SonarQube server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000 with Sonarqube-4.5.1

Tags: linux, maven, sonarqube

I have recently setup Sonarqube-4.5.1 on my linux machine ( x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux ).
I am able to start sonar with `./sonar.sh start` command. On checking the sonar status with `./sonar.sh status` command, it says `SonarQube is running (18493)` but when i try to open the dashboard url `http://ip-address:9000` it shows "**Connection refused**" message on the browser.

On running the `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000` command i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project app-dao: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar failed: SonarQube server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'. Connection refused -> [Help 1]
```

I also tried the solution mentioned at [maven connecting to Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7518574) and added the following entries in my maven's conf/settings.xml file, but still unable to fix the issue.

```
<profile>
  <id>sonar</id>
  <activation>
   <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <!-- EXAMPLE FOR MYSQL -->          
    <sonar.jdbc.username>admin</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>admin</sonar.jdbc.password>            
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: It is not clear whether Sonar is running on another machine than the one you browse/maven from? Which IP does Sonar bind to?

Comment: Sonar and Maven, both are setup on the same machine. "Which IP does Sonar bind to?" how should i check this. It would be localhost as i have not updated any default properties.

Comment: Run this in a shell to verify SonarQube is listening on port 9000: `$ netstat -an | grep 9000`

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue this morning.  Resolved it by configuring the server to access the MySQL database: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing

You want to edit the {sonar_home}/conf/sonar.properties and uncomment the url, username, and password.

You might have to add a new database user if you would like.

Comment: I will try out this solution, but the thing is i have also setup Sonar on a windows machine and there it works fine without editing the default properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the Sonar Server first.

Go to `\sonar-3.5.1\bin\windows-x86-32` and double click on `StartSonar.bat`

Answer (score 0):

In conf folder in installation directory sonar.properties file has a property sobar.web.host. If you have explicitly defined a ip this could cause this issue. Comment out and restart the server. This worked for me.