# SonarQube try to use 'org.h2.Driver' when MySql has been specified instead

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

Requirement is to `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` deploy/install snapshots from Machine Maven to Machine SonarQube which will store it in Machine MySql which has a MySql database.
Machine MySql is only visible to Machine SonarQube. Machine SonarQube is visible to the intranet which everyone within the intranet can access it.
When running `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` from Machine Maven the following error occurs:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project my-project: Fail to connect to database: Cannot load JDBC
>   driver class 'org.h2.Driver' -> [Help 1]

Machine Maven has the following profile in ~/.m2/settings.xml:

> ```
> <profile>
>     <id>sonar</id>
>     <activation>
>         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
>     </activation>
>     <properties>
>         <sonar.host.url>https://sonarqube.myproject.com</sonar.host.url>
>     </properties>
> </profile>
> ```

sonar-maven-plugin has been added as per documentation found in [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Also sonar-maven-plugin has been added as a dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I know the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven) asks for jdbc driver, url, username and password to be specified in maven settings sonar profile properties which I don't want to expose to other people, so this has been specified in the Machine SonarQube conf/sonar.properties

Is there a way to depoly/install these snapshots to Machine MySql through Machine SonarQube run the 'mvn clean install sonar:sonar' from Machine Maven?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In this post [Sonar fails to connect to mySQL always tries jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480744/sonar-fails-to-connect-to-mysql-always-tries-jdbch2tcp-localhost-sonar), it´s appear your properties are incompleted.

Try to add the follow properties to the "sonar profile" in your maven settings file *~/.m2/settings.xml* :

```
<profile>
  <id>sonar</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>user_of_the_sonar_database</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>password_of_the_userdatabase</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

**Note**: Your `<sonar.jdbc.url></sonar.jdbc.url>` depens on the database you use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm aware that which ever database is used it's sensitive details will be exposed in the profile. However, I'm looking for a solution where I could have a job in a CI such Jenkins or Bamboo where only the Sonar Host Url would be enough. I don't want to expose DB details in pom.xml where everybody have access to it. The DB details would be stored in the Sonarqube Machine in the conf/sonar.properties file where only the Sys Admin have access to it. If anyone knows how this could be done, please let me know. Cheers :-)

Comment: I'm also interested in the same thing as SylvesterAbrue.. I hope someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Apparently they changed this after 5.2, you no longer need the JDBC connection properties in the maven settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7520119/400503

Answer (score 0):

To use in jenkins, it must configure the sonar plugin settins in the jenkins management/sonarQube server/advanced settins -> the DDBB URL like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonardb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance

user=sonar
pwd =sonnar
```

for sonarQube version 5.1 or lower. In 5.2 or prior the DDBB is embeded and this is not necesary.