# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException

Tags: maven, java-8, sonarqube, pom.xml

[image]* when I run mvn sonar:sonar , I got this error. I tried many methods to solve it and had done many changes in pom.xml file but unable to find the correct solution.
I used java8, Sonar Qube of 7.6 version.

***How to integrate the maven project on SonarQube or how to generate a report of the maven project in pom.xml file?***

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project BankAccount: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]**

Unable to find the solution, can anyone give the solution
of this error?

Here is the pom.xml file of my project.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.bank.account.details</groupId>
    <artifactId>BankAccount</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BankAccount</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
               
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
  <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
-->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <!-- minimal version of SonarQube to support. -->
      <version>7.6</version>
      <!-- mandatory scope -->
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>       
            <!--  
             <plugin>
          <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
        </plugin>
        -->
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0.372</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <!-- the entry-point class that extends org.sonar.api.SonarPlugin -->
          <pluginClass>com.mycompany.sonar.reference.ExamplePlugin</pluginClass>
          <!-- advanced properties can be set here. See paragraph "Advanced Build Properties". -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>sonar</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<properties>
<!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
<sonar.host.url>
http://localhost:9000
</sonar.host.url>
</properties>
</profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run mvn you need to provide link to you SonarQube

you can find solution here
[maven connecting to Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518574/maven-connecting-to-sonar)

Answer (score 0):

The NPE could be caused by a missing permission in your Sonar project.
Make sure the token (if you use one) matches a user with the proper rights.
In your Sonar server, open the project's settings, then in the permissions, double check the user's tick boxes.